# database optimization issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization

i have a table `Students` which contains the following colums:
 `Id,FirstName,LastName,Adress`. 
The colum Adress will contain just the street adress.

the question is: will it be better for the database optimization to isolate the column `Adress` in a different table?

Comment: What to you want to optimize? What's the content of the column "Address"? Does it contain the full address of a person? If so, at lest split it to different columns for street, city, zip code etc... You have to tell as more about your database/table design if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you seperate it into another table, you can have more than one address per person. If you seperate it to two different tables, an Address table and a StudentAddress table to map the two together, you can make sure that a single address is shared between people or even track a history of addresses for one person. Further, in a seperate table you can break the address down into columns so that you can easily search by City or Province or Country.

You can't do any of that putting an Address into a single column with the Student table.

Comment: On top, a City, Country table with a foreign ke will significantly cut down database size and make queries faster (how many countries you deal with)?. At least un most cases.

Comment: @TomTom ABsolutely agree. Normalization is an optimization technique. For storage, performance, ease of use...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are going to treat that Address. If you will need to treat it as different entity, i.e. link single address to several Students or vice versa e.t.c., then you should do normalization.
If address is only attribute of entity student then leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

For full proper data structures to manage addresses: THe Data Model Ressource BOok, Volume 1. It is a LOT more complicate to get right than you think.